# App to block applications

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I am designing an application blocker app
I am monitoring the top stack activity to block apps in a thread which is started in a Service.
I have a list of allowed apps stored in temp variables and in sharedpreference

The problems are:

1. When android is low in memory it kills my service and my app is no longer active. How can I overcome this ??
2. If I am starting my service again in onDestroy() and reading back list of blocked apps from sharedpreference I am not able to read this list from sharedprefereance  when android kills my service

What can I do to overcome above problems to keep my application long running?

Comment: Did you figure a way to successfully create an app locking application? I need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For 1. If you override `onStartCommand()` in your service to return `START_STICKY`, it should keep your service running.